# SQL Pivot with Specifying Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I want to set up a pivot statement like below, but instead of passing column values I just want it to return all; I want to leave the parenthesis at the bottom empty (i.e. Sum(fldNI) FOR fldCI IN ( )....

```
SELECT * 
    FROM    
(
    SELECT fldPK
          ,fldFPK
          ,fldNI
          ,fldCI
    FROM qryOne 
) as x
PIVOT
(
    Sum(fldNI) FOR fldCI IN ()
) as p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the PIVOT function the values must be known in order to convert them into columns.  If you do not know the values ahead of time, then you will have to implement dynamic SQL to get the result. The dynamic SQL code will create the list of values that will be converted into columns, this list is then concatenated to a query string that is executed.

The code will be similar to:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(fldCI) 
                    from qryOne
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT fldPK, fldFPK, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
               SELECT fldPK
                    ,fldFPK
                    ,fldNI
                    ,fldCI
              FROM qryOne 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(fldNI)
                for fldCI in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I just edited my post to include the full spectrum of what I am dealing with. I've been trying to figure out how to get all the code to work dynamically but it won't work.

Comment: @tripleddev If you have another question then you should post a new one with the new issue, don't edit your original question. But you cannot include dynamic SQL in a function. I have rolled back your changes, please post a new question with the details on the inline function